# Geometry Question on semicirlces constructed inside a triangle

Tags: geometry

In a right triangle ABC with right angle at vertex C, a semicircle is constructed with center P on leg AC so that the semicircle is tangent to leg BC at C, tangent to the hypotenuse AB and intersects leg AC at Q between A and C. The ratio of AQ to QC is 2:3.If BC=12, then what is the value of AC?

The answer is 8 radical 10, but i'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: Please do not vandalize posted questions, including your own. Rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

Denote by $X$ the point where the circle touches $AB$. Note that $AQ:QC=2:3$ implies $AQ:QP:PC=4:3:3$. Finally, note $\triangle ABC\sim\triangle APX$, so $AB:BC=AP:PX$. We have $AB=\sqrt{AC^2+12^2}$, $AP=\frac{7}{10}AC$ and $PX=PC= \frac{3}{10}AC$. Now return everything in $AB:BC=AP:PX$ and calculate $AC$.

**Edit.** Calculation:
$$\sqrt{AC^2+12^2}:12= \frac{7}{10}AC:\frac{3}{10}AC= 7:3$$
$$3\sqrt{AC^2+12^2}= 7\cdot 12=84$$
$$\sqrt{AC^2+12^2}= 28$$
$$AC^2=28^2-12^2=(28-12)(28+12)=16\cdot 40= 2^6\cdot 10$$
$$AC= 8\sqrt 10$$

Comment: thank you. I keep getting AC = 28, but i think AB = 28, do you know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: @Mathmini I edited the answer to include the calculation. I get $AC=8\sqrt{10}$.